# solution of Brachistochrone Problem with friction

Tags: euler-lagrange-equation

from

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrachistochroneProblem.html

I found the EL equation (29) and the parametric solution equations $~(32)~,(33)~$.

**Eq. (29)**
\begin{align*}
  &{~(1+y'^2)\,(1+\mu\,y')+2(y-\mu\,x)\,y''=0}\tag 1
\end{align*}
**Eq. (32),(33)**
\begin{align*}
 &{x=k \left( \theta-\sin \left( \theta \right) +\mu\, \left( 1-\cos
 \left( \theta \right)  \right)  \right)}\\
&{y={k} \left( 1-\cos \left( \theta \right) +\mu\, \left( \theta+\sin
 \left( \theta \right)  \right)  \right)}
\end{align*}
with:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{d\theta}}{\frac{dx}{d\theta}}$$

and

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=
\frac{\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}{\frac{dx}{d\theta}}$$

in Eq. (1) , the result is not equal zero  , why ??

for  solution of Brachistochrone Problem with out friction $~\mu=0~$
I obtain that Eq (1) is qual zero.

---

**Edit**

those equations  are the solutions of equation (1)

$$~x(\theta)=k\,(~\theta+\theta_0+\sin(\theta+\theta_0)-\mu\,\cos(\theta+\theta_0))\\
~y(\theta)=k\,[1+\cos(\theta+\theta_0)+\mu^2+\mu(\theta+\theta_0+\sin(\theta+\theta_0))]$$

where $~\theta_0~$ is a constant to adapt the initial condition.

for example $~\mu=0~,\theta_0=-\pi~$  you obtain

[image]

so which solutions are the correct one ??

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/772853/2451

Answer (score 1):

starting with
\begin{align*}
&\mathcal{L}=\sqrt{\frac{1+y'^2}{y-\mu\,x}} \quad\text{with}\\
& y=z+\mu\,x~,y'=z'+\mu\\
&\mathcal{L}=\sqrt{\frac{1+(z'+\mu)^2}{z}}
\end{align*}
and because $~\mathcal{L}~$ is independent of x the energy $~E~$ is constant
\begin{align*}
  &E(z'~,z)= z'\,\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial z'}-\mathcal{L}=C\quad\Rightarrow\\
  &\frac{1}{E^2}\bigg|_{(z'=y'-\mu~,z=y-\mu\,x)}=\frac{(1+y'^2)\,(y-\mu\,x)}{(1+y'^2)^2}=c
\end{align*}

to addapt the initial condition $~y(0)=0~$ we transfer  $~y\mapsto\,y-y_0~$ thus

\begin{align*}
 &c=\frac{(1+y'^2)\,(y-y_0-\mu\,x)}{(1+y'^2)^2}\tag 1
\end{align*}

solve equation (1) with
\begin{align*}
 &y'=\cot\left(\frac{1}{2}\theta\right)\quad,c=2\\
 &\boxed{x=k \left( \theta-\sin \left( \theta \right) +\mu\, \left( 1-\cos
 \left( \theta \right)  \right)  \right)}\qquad\qquad (32)
\end{align*}
for $~y~$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
 &y=\left( 2\,{\mu}^{2}+\mu\, \left( \theta+\sin \left( \theta \right)
 \right) -\cos \left( \theta \right) +{y_0}+1 \right) ~,\text{and with}~,
 y_0=-{2\,\mu^2}{k}\quad\Rightarrow\\
 &\boxed{y={k} \left( 1-\cos \left( \theta \right) +\mu\, \left( \theta+\sin
 \left( \theta \right)  \right)  \right)~}\qquad\qquad (33)\\
 &y(0)=0
\end{align*}
the EL equation (29) with $~y\mapsto y+y_0~$ is:
\begin{align*}
  &\boxed{~(1+y'^2)\,(1+\mu\,y')+2(y-y_0-\mu\,x)\,y''=0}\tag 2
\end{align*}
equations $~(32)~(33)~$ are also the solution of equation (2)

so we have to modified the EL equation to get it equal zero.